# Can't assign properties to window.event (or data property) in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So,
I'm using event bubbling to capture child DOM events...  I'm attaching click events to a `div` wrapper and also attaching click events to that wrapper's children... like so:

```
<div onclick="foo();">
    <div onclick="bar();">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>

function foo() {
    alert(window.event.abc.one);
};

function bar() {
    window.event.abc = {one: "23"};   
};
```

As you can see, I'm assigning a custom object to `abc`.  I'm using this as a way to send messages to click handlers further up the chain... and avoid using closures on every child element.  In other browsers, you can assign whatever you like to the `event` object... and this works very well.

However (of course), this does not work in IE.  I tried using the "data" property on the event object, but this only allows strings.

Any other way I can accomplish this same functionality without using a closure on every child object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty, but this should work. [Box9 the magnificent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9) suggested something I overlooked, and that is, if something sets a property before it bubbles to `bar()` (for example, an event handler on a descendent of your inner `div`), it will be overwritten.

```
var msg = {};

// When the event bubbles up to document, we'll reset it to an empty object
// literal, ready for new information to be attached to it.
document.onclick = function()  { msg = {} };

function foo() {
    alert(msg.one);
};

function bar() {
    // Assign this property only, so if something else had attached a property
    // to `msg`, it will remain intact.
    msg.one = "23";   
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could assign `msg = {}` on `document.onclick`. Then you don't need to know which event handler triggers first (if there are multiple layers).

Comment: @Box9 Cheers, I may just define it with `{}` instead (did I miss something)?

Comment: Not quite what I meant, though I'm just guessing what the OP wants anyway. I'm imagining a series of event handlers each adding data to the event as it bubbles up, rather than just one. If there's a child of the `bar` element, then assigning a new object in `bar` will replace any values added by descendants. Instead of initializing the `msg` object at the lowest element, you could initialize it first, then reset it once it bubbles to `document`, ready for the next event.